# Json Traverse Problem, not able to traverse values

Tags: php, javascript, json

I m getting the below return from ajax call but not able to traverse it please please help.

```
{
    "1": {
        "tel1": null, 
        "status": "1", 
        "fax": "",     
        "tel2": null,  
        "name": "sh_sup1", 
        "country": "Anguilla", 
        "creation_time": "2010-06-02 14:09:40",
        "created_by": "0",
        "Id": "85",
        "fk_location_id": "3893",
        "address": "Noida",
        "email": "sh_sup1@shell.com",
        "website_url": "http://www.noida.in",
        "srk_main_id": "0"
    },
    "0": {
        "tel1": "Ahemdabad",
        "status": "1",
        "fax": "",
        "tel2": "Gujrat",
        "name": "Bharat Petro",
        "country": "India",
        "creation_time": "2010-05-31 15:36:53",
        "created_by": "0",
        "Id": "82",
        "fk_location_id": "3874",
        "address": "THIS is test address",
        "email": "bp@india.com",
        "website_url": "http://www.bp.com",
        "srk_main_id": "0"
    },
    "count": 2
}
```

Comment: I reformatted it.  You also need to tell us what language you're using, what kind of traversal you want, and what you've tried.  Also, that's odd JSON.  All the numbers are strings, and it uses an object with "0" and "1" keys instead of the more natural array.

Comment: I m using php , i encoded the php array from server using json_encode
and returned it back to client , now i want to traverse this json data what i m getting using javascript only.Count can be removed its just added to count the number of elements forming.Please suggest

Comment: @Jos: Well... you used `json_encode` to encode it...so why don't you use `json_decode` to decode it back..? Then access whatever variables you want just like you would normally with a PHP associative array..

Comment: @Mark, I presume because he's trying to read it in JavaScript.  @Jos, show your encoding code.   I think part of the issue is the count.  That shouldn't be necessary if it's a true JSON array, and it will force PHP to export as a JSON object.

Comment: Hi Mark,

I m getting the json data in javascript function as below in terms of msg and i want to access name from 0 element.how to do this please suggest.


 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: actionHandler,
  timeout: 39000,
  datatype: "json",
  data: "id="+mainContactID,
  beforeSend: function(msg)
  {
   
  },
  success: function(msg)
  {   
    
   var jsonRetData = msg;
   alert(msg);
  }  
 });

Comment: and on server file i m doing 

$json =json_encode($mainConData);

mainconData contains the array from database.

Comment: Well, you can start by not adding the count to mainConData.

Comment: Matthew i have already deleted the count but dont know how to acces name , email etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very easily:

```
for(i = 0; i < msg.count; i++) {
   alert(msg[i]['name']);
}
```

But the structure of your JSON object is not that good for several reasons:

- It does not reflect the structure of the actual data
  With this I mean, that you actually have an **array** of objects. But in your JSON object the elements of the array are represented as **properties** of an object.
- You have invalid JavaScript object property names.
  Properties for objects in JavaScript are not allowed to start with numbers. But with `msg = { "1": {...}}` you have a number as property.
  Fortunately it is not that bad because you can access this property with "array like" access `msg["1"]` (instead of the "normal way", `msg.1`). But I would consider this as bad practice and avoid this as much as possible.

---

Hence,  as Matthew already proposes, it would be better to remove the `count` entry from the array **on the server side, *before*** you sent it to the client. I.e. you should get a JSON array:

```
[{
     "tel1": "Ahemdabad",
     "status": "1",
     // etc.
 },
 {    
     "tel1": null,
     "status": "1",
     // etc.
 }]
```

You don't need `count` as you can get the length of the array with `msg.length` and you can traverse the array with:

```
for(var i in msg) {
    alert(msg[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all i managed to get it done , i have changed the complete format of json return and hurrayyy its over.But thanks again for thinking loudly with me for the problem.

Comment: Both JavaScript and JSON objects can have numeric property names.  It's not a good idea, but it is valid.